How to create a user space buffer from within a Linux kernel driver?
I'm trying to update an old kernel driver to run under Debian Bookworm, but I've run into trouble. Because this driver wraps around a different serial driver (e.g. /dev/ttyS4), it uses filp_open() on that other driver, then calls file operations (ioctl, read, write) to control that other driver, with any buffer/struct parameters bounced to/from user space.
However, to achieve this, I believe that the (calling) kernel driver has to (somehow) create buffers in user space to use to call the other driver (the original code used mm_seg_t etc). I thought all I'd have to do was vmalloc() a block of memory, kmalloc() a block of page pointers, then call get_user_pages() on the block. But when I try this, get_user_pages() is returning -14 (EFAULT).
Here's my current attempt:
// Calculate page-aligned size of user data block
size_t szUserdata_sizeof = PAGE_ALIGN(sizeof(struct userdata));

// Calculate the number of pages
int iUserdata_numpages = szUserdata_sizeof / PAGE_SIZE;

// Allocate block of memory in kernel space
struct userdata * pstUserdata_kernel = vmalloc(szUserdata_sizeof);
if (pstUserdata_kernel == NULL) { return -ENOMEM; }

// Array to store pointers to the pinned pages
static struct page **papstUserdata_pages;
papstUserdata_pages = kmalloc(iUserdata_numpages * sizeof(struct page *), GFP_KERNEL);
if (papstUserdata_pages == NULL) { return -ENOMEM; }

// Determine the (fake) user-space address we will be using
unsigned long ulUserdata_user = (unsigned long)pstUserdata_kernel;

// Use get_user_pages() to pin the buffer's pages, simulating user-space memory
long ret = get_user_pages(ulUserdata_user, iUserdata_numpages, FOLL_WRITE, papstUserdata_pages, NULL);

It feels like I'm missing a really tiny piece of the jigsaw here, what do I need to do to get this working? Thanks!
Note: I do know that a more modern (and better) way of having a kernel driver control a different tty kernel driver would be to use tty_kopen_exclusive() etc: but that would mean rewriting most of this driver from scratch (which I don't think I want to do).

Why not create the buffer in userspace and pass a pointer to the driver?

Once the driver gets modprobed, it needs to control the other serial driver really quickly (long before there's any user space action). This is why it needs to fake up some user space memory long before any user space client interactions could happen. Good question, though!
